# Aggregate function on an expression containing subquery not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

My stored procedure is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[getcommission] 
    @fromdate date,
    @todate date
AS
BEGIN
    select d.dname,sum(s.amount)as amount,sum(CASE 
            WHEN d.grade = 'A' 
               THEN s.amount*0.01 
            WHEN d.grade = 'B' 
               THEN s.amount*0.01 
               ELSE s.amount*0.05
       END) as commission,
       sum(CASE
            WHEN (select grade from tblDealer where dcode=d.parentcode)='A'
                THEN s.amount*0.01
            WHEN (select grade from tblDealer where dcode=d.parentcode)='B'
                THEN s.amount*0.01
            WHEN (select grade from tblDealer where dcode=d.parentcode)='C'
                THEN s.amount*0.05
            ELSE NULL
          END) as partialcommission,
       sum(CASE 
            WHEN d.grade = 'A' 
           THEN s.amount*0.01 
        WHEN d.grade = 'B' 
           THEN s.amount*0.01 
           ELSE s.amount*0.05
     END + 
     CASE
        WHEN (select grade from tblDealer where dcode=d.parentcode)='A'
            THEN s.amount*0.01
        WHEN (select grade from tblDealer where dcode=d.parentcode)='B'
            THEN s.amount*0.01
        WHEN (select grade from tblDealer where dcode=d.parentcode)='C'
            THEN s.amount*0.05
        ELSE NULL
   END) as totalcommission

from tblSales as s
inner join tblDealer as d on d.dcode=s.dcode where s.date between @fromdate 
and @todate 
group by d.dname

END
```

I want sum of rows having same dname for `amount`, `commission`, `partialcommission` and `totalcommission`. Problem is that sum() is not working for `commission` and `partialcommission` fields since they contains sub query in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use sum operation in Case statement. you can try following code. You might have to add to few columns into group by statement.

```
select d.dname,sum(s.amount)as amount,sum(CASE 
            WHEN d.grade = 'A' 
               THEN s.amount*0.01 
            WHEN d.grade = 'B' 
               THEN s.amount*0.01 
               ELSE s.amount*0.05
       END) as commission,
       CASE
            WHEN (select grade from tblDealer where dcode=d.parentcode)='A'
                THEN sum(s.amount*0.01)
            WHEN (select grade from tblDealer where dcode=d.parentcode)='B'
                THEN sum(s.amount*0.01)
            WHEN (select grade from tblDealer where dcode=d.parentcode)='C'
                THEN sum(s.amount*0.05)
            ELSE NULL
          END as partialcommission,
       CASE 
            WHEN d.grade = 'A' 
           THEN sum(s.amount*0.01)
        WHEN d.grade = 'B' 
           THEN sum(s.amount*0.01)
           ELSE sum(s.amount*0.05)
     END + 
     CASE
        WHEN (select grade from tblDealer where dcode=d.parentcode)='A'
            THEN sum(s.amount*0.01)
        WHEN (select grade from tblDealer where dcode=d.parentcode)='B'
            THEN sum(s.amount*0.01)
        WHEN (select grade from tblDealer where dcode=d.parentcode)='C'
            THEN sum(s.amount*0.05)
        ELSE NULL
   END as totalcommission

from tblSales as s
inner join tblDealer as d on d.dcode=s.dcode where s.date between @fromdate 
and @todate 
group by d.dname
```

Answer (score 0):

Subqueries are not allowed as the arguments to aggregation functions.  In this case, a `LEFT JOIN` is an apt replacement:

```
select d.dname,sum(s.amount)as amount,
       sum(case when d.grade = 'A' then s.amount*0.01 
                when d.grade = 'B' then s.amount*0.01 
                else s.amount*0.05
           end) as commission,
      sum(case when dp.grade = 'A' then s.amount*0.01
               when dp.grade = 'B' then s.amount*0.01
               when dp.grade = 'C' then s.amount*0.05
          end) as partialcommission,
      sum(case when d.grade = 'A' then s.amount*0.01 
               when d.grade = 'B' then s.amount*0.01 
               else s.amount*0.05
          end) + 
      sum(case when dp.grade = 'A' then s.amount*0.01
               when dp.grade = 'B' then s.amount*0.01
               when dp.grade = 'C' then s.amount*0.05
          end) as totalcommission
from tblSales s inner join
     tblDealer d
     on d.dcode = s.dcode left join
     tblDealer dp
     on dp.dcode = d.parentcode
where s.date between @fromdate  and @todate 
group by d.dname
```

END